# How do I link to my old Stack Overflow account?

Tags: discussion, login

I've had a Stack Overflow account for years, which I logged into through my Yahoo! ID.  User ID was dewtell.  Today I tried to log in through my Yahoo! ID as usual, and SO created a new ID for me with 1 reputation.  I don't know if this is related to the Yahoo/Verizon/Oath merger, but I suspect it might be, since I had to agree to new terms of service under Oath in the process of signing on. Is there a way for me to link to my old account/log in with it, so that I can preserve my old reputation and access to all the associated features?  I tried to ask this on StackOverflow Meta, but you need at least 5 reputation to ask a question there, and that's a problem for me at the moment...

Comment: See [I accidentally created two accounts, how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: The process to follow is linked above, that should let you contact the right people at SO to process the merge. I see two different emails on these accounts, so you might still be able to log into the other one with the older email you used for that account. If not, the merge process should give you access to the older account using your current credentials.

Comment: For future reference, the network wide meta, [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) doesn't have a reputation limit. That is probably a better option then simply posting on main.